# Finding Open/closed loop transfer function

Tags: control, control-system

I plan to determine the open/close loop transfer function of the attached motor. I have been able to combine K(s) to 1/s in series but am not too sure of how to add up 12/pi outside the summing junction and what to use as the gain(either tetha 0/teta 1 or teta 0/V1(s).

Also how to use this to determine the closed loop of the system
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Start by putting some equations on it: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIcREy.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The output of A is called Vout, but clearly ....

\$V_{out} = A(V_{in} - B\cdot V_{out})\$

This boils down to \$\dfrac{V_{out}}{V_{in}} = \dfrac{A}{1+AB}
\$

Comment: Thanks Andy, In finding the forward path for the open loop I have added 12/pi that is not in the feedback path. does that look ok.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Together with the first block (12/Pi) and Andy aka`s answer you will be able to find the closed-loop transfer function.

2.) The open-loop function is the product of all forward blocks (without the feedback path). This expression should not be confused with the "loop gain" which is simply the product A*B (using Andy aka`s notation)-

3.) The full closed-loop gain is defined as the ratio of two angles (tetha,0/teta,i).

Comment: LvW,  Going by your second comment, for the open loop transfer function, all the forward function including 12/pi with input(teta i) & output(Vi(s)). Thats what I've done before posting the diagram.

Comment: Whats a unity negative feedback?

Answer (score 0):

The relation between open loop F(s) and closed loop H(s) is H(s)=F(s)/1+F(s) if and only if the feedback is 1. In your case the feedbak is 12/pi, but also the setpoint is multiplied with same, so the solution of your homework is: 
- find how to move the feedback into the loop and make feedback =1, then some coeficient will cancell out and use the formula openv vs. closed loop with fbck=1

Comment: Quote: "....find how to move the feedback into the loop and make feedback =1"...My comment: For which purpose such an unnecessary procedure?

Comment: @LvW Because this is a classic exercise at univeristy, and two same gains 12/pi are pointing that professor wants exactly that thing.

Comment: Ahhh - yes, this could be the case.